# proof about a lemma of divisibility

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if $a|b$ and $b \neq 0$ then $|a| \leq |b|$

Approach:
Assume $|a| > |b|$ and $b=ak$ for some integer k

$$|a| > |ak|$$ which is a contradiction becasuse $|a||k|=|ak|>|a|$ or $|ak|=a$ if $k=1$

Comment: You're close but slightly off. All you know in general is that $|ak|\ge |a|$. It could actually be the case that you have equality.

Comment: No need to move |b|  or |ak| back and forth across the > sign.  And, state why you can replace b with ak.

Comment: Hint: absolute value is multiplicative and $|a| \geq 0$ for all $a$ and $|a| = 0$ if and only if $a = 0$.

Comment: A direct proof would be better.

Answer (score 3):

The argument is sound, but too long and unnecessarily by contradiction.

Since $a\mid b$, we have $b=ak$, for some integer $k$. Since $b\ne0$, also $k\ne0$, so $|k|\ge1$. Therefore
$$
|a|\cdot|k|\ge|a|\cdot1=|a|
$$
and so
$$
|a|\le |ak|=|b|
$$

Comment: It is very common as a novice mathematician to get sucked into using proof by contradiction when it is not necessary. This is a great example of such an occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

I think a direct proof is easier. As an alternative approach:

Note that $a \neq 0$. $a \vert b$ implies that there exists some $k \in \mathbb{Z} $ so that $b=ak $. But then $$|b|=|ak|=|a|\cdot |k| \geq |a| \cdot 1=|a|$$

For your proof, you should clarify where you are using the definition of divides. Also note that $ |ak| >a $ is false if $k=1$.